# Angular Loading Image Inside of a Promise not able to pass Image object thru resolve()

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I have a promise to load a image. I just want to printout the image size after loading it. I am getting an error on image.width and image.height for

> "Property 'width' does not exist on type '{}'."

What am I missing?

```
addImageProcess(src){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let img = new Image()
      img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(img));
      img.addEventListener("error", err => reject(err));
      img.src = src;
    })
}

this.addImageProcess(imgData)
  .then(img  => console.log("------ image.width = " + img.width + ", image.height = " + img.height))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be explicit about what sort of promise you're creating, because typescript can't automatically figure that out itself. So in your version of typescript it's defaulting to `Promise<{}>`, and from [version 3.5 onward](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#typescript-35) it would be `Promise<unknown>`. Neither an empty object nor `unknown` have a width property, hence the error later on.

The fix is to either add an explicit return type to addImageProcess:

```
  addImageProcess(src: string): Promise<HTMLImageElement>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let img = new Image()
      img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(img));
      img.addEventListener("error", err => reject(err));
      img.src = src;
    })
  }
```

or add it to the promise constructor itself:

```
  addImageProcess(src: string) {
    return new Promise<HTMLImageElement>((resolve, reject) => {
      let img = new Image()
      img.addEventListener("load", () => resolve(img));
      img.addEventListener("error", err => reject(err));
      img.src = src;
    })
  }
```

or do both if you like :)